# Sending parameters to an API using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, smartsheet-api

I have worked with REST APIs in Python but have no idea how to use them in node.js. I'm trying to build an application that pulls data from a user's smartsheet account. The [smartsheet API page](http://www.smartsheet.com/developers/api-documentation) gives cURL examples. Could you please tell me how to call [this](http://www.smartsheet.com/developers/api-documentation#h.3bqgetcbgx89) API and pass parameters to it in node.js?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use request module. Since I don't have an access token I am getting `{"errorCode":1002,"message":"Your Access Token is invalid."}`

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
    url: 'https://api.smartsheet.com/1.1/sheets',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN'
    }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var info = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(info);
    } else {
        console.log(error);
        console.log(body);
    }
}

request(options, callback);
```